# Como agregar solo números en QLineEdit PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlineedit

Como puedo validar un **`QLineEdit`** para que solo acepte números y aparezca un mensaje de advertencia al ingresar texto?

Dejo el código de mi modulo:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from untitled import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self._clear)
        self.btn3.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.calcmts)


    def _clear(self):
        self.valor1.clear()
        self.valor2.clear()

    def calcmts(self):
            conversion = float(self.valor1.text()) * 3.6
            self.valor2.setText(str(conversion))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que el QLineEdit solo valide valores numericos podemos usar `QIntValidator` o `QDoubleValidator` segun sea el caso.

En tu caso:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        [...]
        self.valor1.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.valor2.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
```